# How to start pentaho BA on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu, pentaho

I'm from a vm with Ubuntu 15.10.
The first time I have installed it on my vm, it worked perfectly. However, now I can't no more start pentaho on Ubuntu 15.10. I write the following instruction in the terminal:

```
./Pentaho/server/biserver-ee/start-pentaho.sh
```

in the folder where Penthao is intalled. However, then it tells me the server has started, but when I type "http://localhost:8080/pentaho/Login" in the browser (mozilla firefox), it loads the page indefinetely and the virtual machine slows down very much, so that I can't do anything else.

I installed mysql server and mysqlworkbench and then pentaho. The first time I used it, it worked. Then I installed pycharm and java following this video: [install pycharm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4hQkcjDbDw) and the next time I tried to use pentaho it didnt' worked. I also used the following instruction:

```
ctlscript.sh start baserver
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sudo -u pentaho /opt/pentaho/biserver-ce/start-pentaho.sh
```

for more info, visit this [website](http://www.thekunit.com/installing-pentaho-business-analysis-server-ubuntu/)

Comment: What's the difference between biserver-ee and biserver-ce?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to write the following instruction:

```
./ctlscript.sh start
```

instead of the instructions I used